White-Listing specific words for Code Analysis rule IDE1006: "These words must begin with upper case characters"
In a C# / .NET project, we have enabled Code Analysis during the build. We use the .editorconfig to customize which rules are enabled/disabled, and the severity (suggestion/warning/error).
One rule which I'm struggling with is IDE1006. In general, this is good to enforce - that we want classes/methods/properties/constants to start with upper case letters.
But we're making an iOS app, and so many of our namespaces include the term iOS. The way I see it:

We could downgrade this rule, but actually we'd rather like to enforce it for everything else except the term iOS.
Refactor the codebase to use Ios or IOS. Seems unnecessary and not a good use of time, and devs have been using iOS for years.
Temporarily disable IDE1006 with a #pragma all over the code - would be very messy.
If only there was a way to have some dictionary, to say that iOS is a special case within the IDE1006 rule. Is this available somehow, that I've missed?

Currently leaning towards the first option, unless we can find the ideal (last) option.
In my research, I found this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-customize-the-code-analysis-dictionary
It suggests that you can add a custom Code Analysis dictionary to your project. But this has no effect. I've been careful to check the steps, but am starting to think that this may not apply to modern .NET? We're using .NET 8.

Customize the Code Analysis Dictionary indicates it supports Visual Studio 2022, by what method did you plan to implement it in Maui?

Unfortunately, the Custom Code Analysis Dictionary only applies to Code Analysis code quality ('CA') naming rules, not code-style ('IDE') naming rules like IDE1006.
The documentation for customizing the Code Analysis Dictionary that you've linked to clearly specifies that:

Terms in the Dictionary/Acronyms/CasingExceptions node are applied to the following code analysis rules:
CA1709: Identifiers should be cased correctly

The CasingExceptions node has no effect on IDE1006.
